# Haskell parsing csv with header to list of lists

Tags: csv, haskell, list-comprehension

New to haskell trying to get a csv file of ints with a header (type string) to output the 2nd to nth rows into a list of lists. eg [[row, 1], [row, 2]..]
so far with the Pipes library, got it to output each row as a list with the numbers as strings, and it prints "Right" for some reason?. eg output: 'Right ["1","3","5"..]' new line 'Right ["32","38","45"]'. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import qualified System.IO as IO
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Data.Text as Text
import qualified Pipes.Csv as PCsv
import Control.Monad (forever)

showPipe :: Proxy () (Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) () String IO b
showPipe = forever $ do
    x::(Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) <- await
    yield $ show x

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Filename? "
    fName <- getLine 
    IO.withFile fName
                IO.ReadMode
                (\handle -> do
                    let producer = (PCsv.decode PCsv.NoHeader 
(PB.fromHandle handle))
                    runEffect ( (producer)>->
                                (showPipe) >->
                                P.stdoutLn)
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `Pipe`, but it looks like you're pulling data out into an `Either`, which conventionally uses the `Right` constructor for data and the `Left` constructor for an error message.

```
data Either a b = Left a | Right b
```

In this case you're building an `Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)`, so your result will either be:

```
:: Left String
```

or

```
:: Right (V.Vector Text.Text)
```

in this case you're getting the latter, and want to `show` the value pulled out of the `Either` monad. You can use `either` to handle both possibilities at once (in much the same way you'd use `maybe` in the `Maybe` monad).

```
showPipe :: Proxy () (Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) () String IO b
showPipe = forever $ do
    x::(Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)) <- await
    let v = either id show x
    yield v
```

This checks if `x` is a `Left a` or a `Right b` and returns either `id a` or `show b` depending. `either` is type

```
either :: (a -> c) -> (b -> c) -> Either a b -> c
-- or, specialized for this case:
either :: (String -> String)
           -> ((V.Vector Text.Text) -> String)
           -> Either String (V.Vector Text.Text)
           -> String
```

Either (a hyuk) way you should be yielding a `String` back to be printed in `main`